# waterfox not listed as installed browser?

Tags: windows-7, browser, windows-registry

Trying to find out a way to programmatically find all the installed browser, I came across [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370732/how-to-find-all-the-browsers-installed-on-a-machine) which points at the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet`.

I have installed Google Chrome, Waterfox and of course IE, but the registry does not list Waterfox. Does anyone know if this is intentional or installation error?

```
> reg  query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet
    (Default)    REG_SZ    IEXPLORE.EXE

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\Google Chrome
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\IEXPLORE.EXE

> dir /b "c:\Program Files\Waterfox\waterfox.exe"
waterfox.exe
```

Comment: Maybe you should contact Waterfox's developers and ask if Waterfox registers itself with the system as a browser.

Answer (score 1):

I think the below link will answer and help address the issue.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd203067%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Regards,
IDEVFH
https://idevfh.com